# Remove all instances of indirect function from range with VBA - type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with code I wrote to remove INDIRECT formulas and replace them with the named range those indirect functions were referencing.  The code works fine until it hits a cell that contains a pretty long formula (4000+ characters)

I'm getting a type mismatch at "DirectPart = Evaluate(IndirectPart)"

I'm guessing the length of my formula is the problem, but don't know what to do to get around it.

```
Sub ButtonParseIndirect_Click()

Dim TheFormula As String
Dim IndirectPart As String
Dim DirectPart As String


Range("A1").Activate

Do Until ActiveCell = Range("FF100")

Range("A1:FF100").Find(what:="INDIRECT").Activate

    TheFormula = ActiveCell.Formula
    Do While InStr(TheFormula, "INDIRECT") > 0
        IndirectPart = Mid(TheFormula, InStr(TheFormula, "INDIRECT") + 9)
        IndirectPart = Left(IndirectPart, InStr(IndirectPart, ")") - 1)
        DirectPart = Evaluate(IndirectPart)
        TheFormula = Replace(TheFormula, "INDIRECT(" & IndirectPart & ")", DirectPart)
    Loop
    ActiveCell.Formula = TheFormula

Loop

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is it possible that the `IndirectPart = Left(IndirectPart, InStr(IndirectPart, ")") - 1)` is not extracting the information correctly? I would think that a formula with 4000+ characters has more than one pair of parenthesis.

Comment: Can you do len on indirectpart?

Comment: Good question. Seeing a sample of your file would be very useful?

Comment: @D_Zab, there are a bunch of parentheis, but the code is working well on other formulas with a bunch of parenthesis, so I'm assuming it's fine.  It's got it done on another file I use in this project.

Comment: @brettdj, Yeah man, I'm lost on this one.  You may have other suggestions for me too.  The main goal is to speed up the calcs by getting rid of this volatile function that appears A LOT.  After what I've cleaned out so far there are still 4663 cells containing multiple instances of Indirect. (up to 45 instances per cell)   :)   There's probably a far smarter way to do what I want!!

Comment: Can you put a sample up in the web for us to look at?

Comment: @brettdj, ... I'm not seeing a way to upload a file.  May be awful silly, but how do I go about that on this site?

Comment: I'm adding some helper cells to simplify and dramatically shorten this repetitive formula.  Just about ready to test it out.  It should work after these changes, but I'd still like to figure out a solution so we all learn.

Comment: @jason no you cant do there here, you would need to use a cloud account, or public file host

Comment: Please:

1. Run the code find a cell that is failing

2. inspect the value of IndirectPart at the point of failing. This will give the name/reference  that is not being resolved.

3. Check the names to see whether they are defined.

4. Paste the indirectpart into a cell as a formula and see what happens.

Comment: @HarveyFrench-Thanks for the help! Here's a the full formula that fails. "=IFERROR(IF(T3="SPEC","",INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(U3)),MATCH(1,(SERIES=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(U3,"[SERIES]")))*FLUTES=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(U3,"(FLUTES]")))*SERIESREVISION=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(U3,"REV]"))),0),MATCH(CONCATENATE(N3,"CM"),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(U3,"[#HEADERS]")),0))),"")"     IndirectPart evaluates to a "CONCATENATE(U3", which is why it's failing.  The value of DirectPart then evaluates to nothing because I'm missing the ")" after U3.  Would a modification to the code be possible, or modify the excel formula?

Comment: Jason. The code you are writing to modify the formulas in your workbook does not cater for all possibilities. The formulas looks pretty mad and it may be possible to simplify them, but that's another matter.  .  If the formulas work, then perhaps you can use the code to change most of them and to ignore ones it can't correctly change.   See My second answer

Comment: @Harvey, I've altered the code to remove the concatenates first, delete the formula altogether if the indirect reference evaluates to "", and then run through the remaining formulas to remove indirect.  I'll post the code once it finishes running (unless it's stuck in an endless loop for some reason).  It worked on the first few cells I pointed it at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked.  Almost.  This IS a solution to the original problem, and I have another to dive into as a result.  This required me modifying my excel formula slightly and adding code to eliminate the "indirect(concatenate" that existed in some places before tackling the remaining indirect functions.

```
Sub ButtonParseIndirect_Click()

Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Dim RngStr As String

RngStr = "A1:ZZ1000"


'************************************************'
'                PARSE CONCATENATES              '
'************************************************'

    Do Until Range(RngStr).Find(what:="INDIRECT(CONCATENATE") Is Nothing

    On Error GoTo Skip1

    Range(RngStr).Find(what:="INDIRECT(CONCATENATE").Activate

        TheFormula = ActiveCell.Formula
        Do While InStr(TheFormula, "INDIRECT(CONCATENATE") > 0
            ConcatenatePart1 = Mid(TheFormula, InStr(TheFormula, "INDIRECT(CONCATENATE") + 21)
            ConcatenatePart1 = Left(ConcatenatePart1, InStr(ConcatenatePart1, ",") - 1)

            DirectPart = Evaluate(ConcatenatePart1)
            If DirectPart = "" Then GoTo MakeBlank

            If Mid(TheFormula, InStr(TheFormula, ConcatenatePart1 & "," & """") + Len(ConcatenatePart1) + 1) > 0 Then
                ConcatenatePart2 = Mid(TheFormula, InStr(TheFormula, ConcatenatePart1 & ",") + Len(ConcatenatePart1) + 2)
                Else
                On Error GoTo Skip1
                End If
            ConcatenatePart2 = Left(ConcatenatePart2, InStr(ConcatenatePart2, ")") - 2)

            NewPart = DirectPart & ConcatenatePart2

            MaybeNot = Mid(TheFormula, InStr(TheFormula, ConcatenatePart1 & "," & """" & ConcatenatePart2) + Len(ConcatenatePart1) + 2 + Len(ConcatenatePart2), 1)
                If MaybeNot <> """" Then MaybeNot = ""

            OldPart = Mid(TheFormula, InStr(TheFormula, "INDIRECT(CONCATENATE") + 21)
            OldPart = Left(OldPart, InStr(OldPart, ConcatenatePart2 & MaybeNot & ")") + Len(ConcatenatePart2) + Len(MaybeNot) - 1)

            TheFormula = Replace(TheFormula, "INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(" & OldPart & "))", NewPart)

GoTo SkipThisPart1

MakeBlank:
        TheFormula = ""

SkipThisPart1:
        Loop


        If ActiveCell.HasArray = False Or TheFormula = "" Then
            ActiveCell.Formula = TheFormula

            End If
Skip1:

    Loop

'************************************************'
'                  PARSE INDIRECTS               '
'************************************************'

    MsgBox ("Starting section 2, Indirect only removal")

    Range("A1").Activate

    Do Until Range(RngStr).Find(what:="INDIRECT") Is Nothing

    On Error GoTo Skip2

    Range(RngStr).Find(what:="INDIRECT").Activate

        TheFormula = ActiveCell.Formula
        Do While InStr(TheFormula, "INDIRECT") > 0
            IndirectPart = Mid(TheFormula, InStr(TheFormula, "INDIRECT") + 9)
            IndirectPart = Left(IndirectPart, InStr(IndirectPart, ")") - 1)

            On Error GoTo Skipme2
            DirectPart = Evaluate(IndirectPart)
            TheFormula = Replace(TheFormula, "INDIRECT(" & IndirectPart & ")", DirectPart)
Skipme2:
        Loop

        If ActiveCell.HasArray = False Or TheFormula = "" Then
            ActiveCell.Formula = TheFormula
            Else:
            ActiveCell.FormulaArray = TheFormula
            End If

Skip2:

    Loop

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

As I mentioned, this code works.  The issue that remains I've proven is the length of the formula.  Really not sure how to handle this as the length has to be the length.  ...no way to change it without also changing the data.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What if INDIRECT is not always followed by a ( but a space!
You code line `Evaluate(IndirectPart)` might have a single "(" at the start with none at the end.

Consider:

```
? Mid("barghINDIRECT(BL__GH)BLARGH", InStr("barghINDIRECT(BL__GH)BLARGH", "INDIRECT") + 9)
BL__GH)BLARGH

? Left("BL__GH)BLARGH", InStr("BL__GH)BLARGH", ")") - 1)
BL__GH

? Mid("barghINDIRECT ( BL__GH ) BLARGH", InStr("barghINDIRECT(BL__GH)BLARGH", "INDIRECT") + 9)
( BL__GH ) BLARGH
```

Also, I'm interested to know whether you think writing the cell search as follows would be slower?

```
Dim aCell as Range

For each aCell in [A1:FF100]
    if instr(1, aCell.Value, "INDIRECT") then

        ' use your code
        ' refer to aCell instead of Activecell in your code
        ' this will be quicker and

    end if
next aCell
```

Comment: Harvey, I'm not concerned much with the speed as I'll only be running this code once.  I'm concerned now with just getting it to work on the long formulas, of which as I mentioned in my comment above, there are a lot of.  Also, I appreciate the suggestion about using mid, but there are no instances where there's a space after indirect.

Comment: Harvey, I'm wondering if what you've suggested here with help with the variation you see in my comment above.  ..I just can't figure out what the "blargh" is supposed to be?  Is that just slang for "your code here"?  Kinda having a rough time figuring out what this would need to look like... (I'm not good with code - total newb here.  I've adapted most of what I've used from other posts on this site.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ButtonParseIndirect_Click()

Dim TheFormula As String
Dim IndirectPart As String
Dim DirectPart As String

on error goto 0

Range("A1").Activate

Do Until ActiveCell = Range("FF100")

Range("A1:FF100").Find(what:="INDIRECT").Activate

    TheFormula = ActiveCell.Formula
    Do While InStr(TheFormula, "INDIRECT") > 0
        IndirectPart = Mid(TheFormula, InStr(TheFormula, "INDIRECT") + 9)
        IndirectPart = Left(IndirectPart, InStr(IndirectPart, ")") - 1)

        on error goto skipMe 
        ' if an error occurs ie Evaluate fails, get on with the next cell and leave it as is!
        DirectPart = Evaluate(IndirectPart)
        TheFormula = Replace(TheFormula, "INDIRECT(" & IndirectPart & ")", DirectPart)
    Loop
    ActiveCell.Formula = TheFormula
skipme:
on error goto 0     
Loop

End Sub
```